# Update MsAccess using PyODBC?

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

i try to update a MS Access DB using PyODBC with the following code:

```
import pyodbc
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime

FN = "dataOdd.accdb"
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
fn = path + "/" + FN
msAccess = r"{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}"
connPath = f'Driver={msAccess};DBQ={fn};'

conn = pyodbc.connect(connPath)
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO dataOdds (" \
      "Date," \
      "Name," \
      "Links," \
      "Fixture) " \
      "VALUES (?,?,?,?)" 
cont = [
        datetime.today().date(),
        "ABCDEFGH",
        "ichbineinlink.html",
        "01:  -  Race Test Race"
       ]
cursor.execute(sql, cont)
conn.commit()
```

But i allways get the following error:

```
$ python workAccess.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr\ORDER\escobar\workAccess.py", line 54, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, cont)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. 
(-3502) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I tried also an update before and this works fine:

```
sql = "UPDATE dataOdds " \
      "SET Links = ? " \
      "WHERE Date = ? " \
      "AND Name = ? " \
      "AND Fixture = ?"
cont = [
        "ABC",
        "2022-03-24",
        "Albury",
        "02:35  -  Race 1 Trackpix maiden showcase plate"
       ]
cursor.execute(sql, cont)
conn.commit()
```

Why is the inserting using PyODBC not working?

Comment: I don't know much about Python so I'm not sure what datetime.today().date() returns.  But if it returns a string that Access can interpret as a date (like your UPDATE example uses) it should work.

Comment: Unless your Date column is a text type, that `UPDATE` could not have worked with datetime type. Your `INSERT` query may have erred because *Date* and *Name* are reserved words that should be escaped with square brackets or backticks (or better yet different column names). BTW, why not use Access' `Date()` function and avoid passing it from Python.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem - when i put Date to [Date] everything works.